# Apply Active Directory domain group policy to standalone PC

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy

We have an Active Directory 2003 domain with Windows XP workstations. Many settings on the workstations are configured and locked down via Active Directory domain group policy.

We need to send a few workstations to a remote office that does not have a domain controller or a connection to the domain. We're planning to remove the workstations from the domain and create local users.

How can we apply the Active Directory group policies to the local users on the workstations? Will we be able to manage the policies on the local computers (perhaps via gpedit)? Are there other things we are not anticipating that we should be aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Group Policy for this, that's only available to Domain Members. You can use the [local security policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277395.aspx), but you'd have to configure this on each machine. After you have one set as a template, I believe that `secpol.exe` will let you import/export the config to other standalone machines.

---

If I could give you some advice, look into creating a site-to-site VPN between your main office and the remote offices and installing a DC if possible. It's much more scalable and will save you headaches in the long-run.